# How to display only 4 items per page from an array react and express

Tags: arrays, reactjs, express, react-hooks

I need quick help with React and Express. I have an array of data at my express server and fetched with react hooks useEffect. Currently, the response shows all the data on the same page, I want to display only 4 items per page? My React component has useState, useEffect and the JSX as normal. See my code below from Express. Any kind of help will be nice, thanks.

An array of data on Express server:

```
app.get('/api/surveyoptions', (req, res) => {
const surveyOptions = [
    // { id: 5, title: "How often do you eat meat and dairy?" },
    { id: 1, name: "diet", label: "daily1", value: "daily1"},
    { id: 2, name: "diet", label: "daily2", value: "daily2" },
    { id: 3, name: "diet", label: "daily3", value: "daily3" },
    { id: 4, name: "diet", label: "daily4", value: "daily4" },
    { id: 5, name: "diet", label: "daily5", value: "daily5"},
    { id: 6, name: "diet", label: "daily6", value: "daily6" },
    { id: 7, name: "diet", label: "daily7", value: "daily7" },
    { id: 8, name: "diet", label: "daily8", value: "daily8" }
]
res.json(surveyOptions)
})
```

Comment: google "REST pagination" https://bezkoder.com/react-pagination-material-ui/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what your backend setup is and what database you're using, but in general you do something like this:

1. On frontend you make a request to the api, including the number of the page you need as a query parameter (e.g. you request '/api/surveyoptions?page=3').

*There are different styles of pagination: some prefer page number, some limit/offset. It really depends on the backend/database/etc. For short explanation of each style you can check [this django-rest-framefork doc](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/) for example.

2. Server reads query params, finds pagination-related ones (e.g. we sent page=3, now server knows that we want the 3rd page of results), paginates results and send it back to the client. Server also should know how many items per page you want, or it could be a constant (e.g. always 10 items per page). Applying to your example, server would split surveyOptions array into chunks (10 items per chunk), and send you the 3rd one.

In react you store the page number in state, update it when user selects another page and sent along with the request as described in the first step.